# Append div element and then animate from right to left using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I want to type a message and then when click on submit button call 'shoot' it will be display at the right side of the screen. However, I want the text to animate/slide in from right to left. 
How do i do it?

```js
$('.submmit').click(function() {
  var c = "<div class='movethis' class='width: 40px;height: 50px;position: absolute;right: 0;'>" + $(".mytxt").val() + "</div>";
  $(".putbullet").append(c).animate({ "left": "0px" }, "slow");
  $(".movethis").animate({ "left": "0px" }, "slow");
  $(".movethis").css('right', '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="txt" class="mytxt">
  <input type="button" class="submmit" value="Shoot">
</div>
<div class="areaofcontent" style="width:68%;float:right; background-color:#eee;height:400px;overflow-y:scroll;">
  <div class="putbullet"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a typo: `class='width: `. Should be `style='width: ` [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wq54apd/)

Comment: Slide inside the textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're calling `animate()` on the `.putbullet` element, not the `.movethis` which you append. You also need to set the styles in the `style` attribute, not the `class` - or better yet, put them in an external stylesheet.

Finally, you'll also need to set `position: relative` on the `.putbullet` so that the appended elements are contained within it when they animate. Try this:

```js
$('.submmit').click(function() {
  $('<div class="movethis">' + $(".mytxt").val() + '</div>').appendTo('.putbullet').animate({
    "left": "0px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.putbullet {
  position: relative;
}
.movethis {
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.areaofcontent {
  width: 68%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="txt" class="mytxt">
  <input type="button" class="submmit" value="Shoot">
</div>
<div class="areaofcontent">
  <div class="putbullet"></div>
</div>
```